# Is it okay to close PHP tag inside a function

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently saw a Wordpress plugin which was using functions like this (simplified):

```
<?php

function test(){
    $var = 1;
    ?>

    <div><?=$var?></div>
    <div>Some random stuff here</div>
    <div>Some random stuff here</div>

    <?php
}
?>
```

When there was too much HTML code, they used the method above instead of something like this (which I'm used to):

```
<?php

function test(){
    $var = 1;
    $out = "<div>{$var}</div>";
    $out .= "<div>Some random stuff here</div>";
    $out .= "<div>Some random stuff here</div>";

    echo $out; // or return $out; and then echo test();
}

?>
```

I've used this approach for `foreach` and other loops in template functions, but never have seen such an approach for `functions`.

I think it might be useful in some cases (when we handle too much HTML)

My Questions are:

1. Is this a good practice? (both for Wordpress or other PHP applications) or it might cause some issues?
2. This can only be used for cases we want to directly `echo` HTML when a function is called right?

Comment: It's kind of wordpress history grown coding style. I personally don't like that style. Same as T. Short in his answer said.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I do not like this practice as it makes code hard to read and maintain. However, there are some cases where it is useful.

It works better with `if/else` blocks of large amount of html.

```php
<? if (this) { ?>

html...

<? } else { ?>

html...

<? } ?>
```

I would avoid breaking up functions like that though. Just my opinion. Others might suggest differently.

And answer to your second question: Yes, only use case I can think of at the moment.